# BigQuery Data Transfer API for Scheduled Query

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am using the Node JS library for BigQuery Data Transfer API to create a scheduled query.

I get this error message

BigQuery Data Transfer API has not been used in project xxxxxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting....

I visited the link and the project is not even my project, I do not have access to it and the project number provided is different to the project I have in the request.

I have used user access token in Header Authorization Bearer for OAuth access.

Anyone experience this issue before?

Comment: I don't know about the error. But in general, if you have the access to BigQuery website interface, the menu on the left has "Scheduled Query". You can click on that item and turn on the Data Transfer  API there.

Comment: Can you please check if your current project is the one used in your authentication?